# USB 3.1 hub shown as USB 2.0

Tags: drivers, usb, hardware, usb-device, hardware-compatibility

My problem is the following. My system is detecting my `USB 3.1 Gen1` hub (onboard hub).

First, I confirmed that my motherboard does indeed have support for `USB 3.1`. I have an `Asus H97-PRO` which has obviously the `H97` chipset which does have support for `USB 3.1 Gen1`. You can find listed in the Asus the following `6 x USB 3.1 Gen 1 port(s) (4 at back panel, blue, 2 at mid-board)`. So, my board does have support for USB 3.1 Gen1`.

If I do `lsusb`, I get two `USB 2.0` hubs. I have one `USB 2.0` hub and one `USB 3.1 Gen1` hub.

```
Bus 002 Device 004: ID 04d9:a070 Holtek Semiconductor, Inc. 
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:8001 Intel Corp. 
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:8009 Intel Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

If I do `lsusb -t`. I get the two hubs with a speed of `480M` as expected.

```
/:  Bus 02.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=ehci-pci/2p, 480M
    |__ Port 1: Dev 2, If 0, Class=Hub, Driver=hub/8p, 480M
        |__ Port 4: Dev 4, If 0, Class=Human Interface Device, Driver=usbhid, 12M
        |__ Port 4: Dev 4, If 1, Class=Human Interface Device, Driver=usbhid, 12M
        |__ Port 4: Dev 4, If 2, Class=Human Interface Device, Driver=usbhid, 12M
/:  Bus 01.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=ehci-pci/2p, 480M
    |__ Port 1: Dev 2, If 0, Class=Hub, Driver=hub/6p, 480M
```

Using one of my development boards, which has `USB 3.0`, I can confirm that when connected to a `USB 3.1` port, it is forced to run on `USB 2.0`.

I have already ran `update-usbids`, `update-pciids` and added `iommu=soft` to `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT` in the grub configuration.

I've ran out of ideas. Thanks in advance for everyone who tries to help.

Comment: Before anyone else asks, the `lsusb -t` output does indeed confirm that the kernel only sees USB 2 ports: USB 3 ports would appear as `Class=root_hub, Driver=xhci_hcd/6p, 5000M` (with a varying number of ports of course, the important part here is “5000M”).

Comment: I just answered the question. For some reason the motherboard didn't came with `XHCI` enabled by default which I took for granted. Guess we can't trust in the manufacturers.

Answer (score 4):

Okay, for some reason my motherboard doesn't come with the `XHCI` support enabled by default. So if anyone is experiencing a similar issue just go and check if `XHCI` is enabled in the bios.

Comment: The Intel H97 chipset was released in 2014, when Windows 10 was not yet released and it was still important that installations of Windows 7 (with no built-in USB 3 support in the installer) were as seamless as possible. If the system was set by default to legacy mode, you could install the OS, install the USB 3 drivers and then enable USB 3 with fuss. But if the system was set to prefer USB 3 instead, the user would have to be careful to plug the keyboard and mouse into USB2-only ports for the installation, or there would have been no way to interact with the USB3-unaware OS installer.

Answer (score 1):

xHCI is responsible for working of USB 3 port,
whereas EHCI driver lets USB 2 work.

On **dual-boot** between Windows 10 and Linux Ubuntu 18.04, setting the xHCI to disabled allows the dual boot to function correctly on BIOS under EHCI controller. 
As a result, a USB 3 port acts as a USB 2 port.

Comment: If you’re quoting something, identify the source.   If you aren’t quoting, don’t use quote formatting.